# How to completely purge Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I want to completely uninstall it.

So I've tried these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove code
sudo apt-get purge code
sudo apt-get update
```

And every time when I re-install I see my project that was open from my last use and I still have all my plugins, my themes, keybindings, etc.

What must I do to completely uninstall all settings of Visual Studio Code ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

User specific settings/extensions are located in `$HOME/.config/Code` and `$HOME/.vscode/` so remove those folders manually

Comment: the only straight forward answer for this simple question all over the web. thanks

Comment: it's better if u have given steps to delete

Comment: But isn't this ridiculous. I mean purge command was specifically desgined to delete the config files and any other remnants of the app. Also, what's with the ambiguity, at some places it is called "code", other places "vscode"

Answer (score 3):

```
cd [enter]

sudo rm -rf .vscode
sudo rm -rf  ~/.config/Code

sudo apt purge code

sudo apt autoremove
```

Answer (score 1):

These commands seek to work just fine.

1. `sudo dpkg --purge code`
2. `sudo dpkg --remove code`
3. then uninstall through `gdebi`

Answer (score 0):

use -:
$ sudo snap remove code

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30006208)

Comment: Why do you assume it is installed as a snap?

Comment: cause while finding my question about how to uninstall .code I came to this link (StackOverflow) but I didn't get my answer on StackOverflow I got this answer while trying a lot of things by self and it works for me. So I mention it here. I didn't see the exact cmd(answer) up there. it works for me if it's going to work for someone and save his/her time that's good. It's all my motto. If I do wrong please suggest to me how to improve my mistake.